# How to remove trailing zeros from hexadecimal string?

Tags: java, android, integer, hex

I have hexadecimal string like `02011A020A060AFF4C0010055D18C66C96000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I want to remove all the trailing zeros and convert string to decimal.

I am trying to convert string using

```
long = Integer.parseInt(it, 16)
```

but getting **NumberFormatException** for mentioned string.

Please suggest.

Comment: Even if you remove trailing zeros, I think the decimal equivalent for `02011A020A060AFF4C0010055D18C66C96` will be too large to be stored in an integer.

Comment: Removing trailing zeroes makes it a different number, much as as '1' and '1000000' are different numbers. What use will this different number be?  And, as @kiner_shah notes, it's still too large, even for a long integer - I count 36 digits, which is 144 bits.

Comment: Check out `BigInteger`...

Comment: I tried using BigInteger. But, the I am not sure about converted value is correct or not.

Comment: It makes different after and before removing all trailing zeros.

Comment: Of course the results are different if you remove trailing zeroes.  The notation is positional, decimal  1 is not 10000; Hex AB is not AB0000.

Comment: To determine whether the result of conversion is correct, convert it back to hex again.  If 'b' is your BigInteger value, execute `System.out.println(b.toString(16))` and eyeball the result.

Comment: I can’t believe the operation is sound. Your example string seems to consist of 34 meaningful hex digits followed by 90 zeroes for a total of 124 digits. What if next time the meaningful part happens to end on a zero or two? Then you will be removing too many zeroes and getting an incorrect result. It could even be the case here that really the first 36 digits contain the meaning and only 88 zeroes are waste. 88 would fit wit 11 32-bits words, so might be more likely. But we can’t tell. Can you?

Answer (score 0):

To replace trailing zeroes as per the question

```
   String s = "02011A020A060AFF4C0010055D18C66C96000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
   String t = s.replaceFirst("(00)*$", "");
```

The result is still not representable as `int` or `long`, though. That is a simple fact.

You can use the `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your string represents a very big integer that can not be accommodated into an `int` type of variable. You can parse it to a decimal integer using `BigInteger`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger num = new BigInteger(
                "02011A020A060AFF4C0010055D18C66C96000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                16);
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1601774156032550143629384364472675906890742343243921647127483666720143286838483191778518780074715465142869671834006975796514903403440608079859679232
```

However, if you are just interested to know how to get rid of the trailing zeros from your string, you can replace the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/IQFIAV/1), `0+$` with `""`. However, note that it will change the value of the number e.g. 9 (without a trailing zero) is not equal to 90 (with a trailing zero).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String num = "02011A020A060AFF4C0010055D18C66C96000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        num = num.replaceAll("0+$", "");
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
02011A020A060AFF4C0010055D18C66C96
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `0+`: One or more zero(s)
- `$`: asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: You almost certainly only want to remove pairs of trailing zeroes,  so that ABC000 goes to ABC0 rather than ABC.  Otherwise you've changed the value of each byte. (I agree the OP's purpose is unclear).

Comment: @iggy - Value will be changed anyway i.e. ABC000 is not equal to ABC0 as well.

Comment: My first guess would be that we should only remove multiples of 8 or 16 zeroes. But we cannot know. I hope the asker knows and is able to adapt the answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  -- the value considered as an integer is changed by removing zeroes, of course.  But considered as a sequence of bytes, which I suspect is what this really is (but who knows with this question), removing trailing zero bytes might be a legitimate operation. (But why then convert to a decimal integer?)